# 様子見くらい いいっしょ? I can't make sense out of it

Tags: grammar, meaning, parsing

Mother:当分ここに住むから｡

Son:えっ!? 何だよそれ｡

Mother:カワイイ一人息子が頭 打ったんだ｡

Mother:様子見くらい いいっしょ｡

Here's the question: What does 様子見くらいいいっしょ｡ mean?

> 様子見 = wait-and-see
>
> くらい = about?around? dunno
>
> いいっしょ = it's good, isn't it? it's ok, right? dunno

I'm quite confused
I can't make sense out of it.